# How to implement Single Sign On (SSO) on dotnet webforms using a Auth0 provider

Tags: .net, single-sign-on

I just want to know if there is any way SSO can be imolemented in dotnet webforms (.aspx)

1. I tried following the steps Microsoft has provided in their documentation (where they have used dotnet mvc app) but that obviously didnt work.